# Try to install eclipse on ubuntu for working on c and can't open it because java error

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, ubuntu

I used this guide: http://tutorialforlinux.com/2013/10/18/how-to-install-eclipse-kepler-4-3-for-cc-on-ubuntu-13-10-saucy-3264bit-easy-visual-guide/
 to install eclipse on ubuntu for working on c/c++ and when i try open the eclipse (from the terminal by the order eclipse, like it wrote at this guide) i get the next error message:

A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK)
must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine
was found after searching the following locations:
/opt/eclipse/jre/bin/java
java in your current PATH

Thanks

Comment: what is the output of `java -version` command

Answer (score 0):

Install Java on your machine if that is not Installed and start eclipse again.

http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux

Comment: although I need the eclipse for c/c++ I need to install the java??
What exactly I need: JDK or JRE ?
Thanks

Comment: You need Java because Eclipse is written in Java.

Answer (score 0):

That error seems self explanatory, in order to run eclipse you must have a java JRE/JDK installed.

You can install the OpenJDK JRE by running this command in your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```